# How to run spring boot main class via docker exec command

Tags: spring-boot, docker

How to run spring boot main class via docker exec command. This is not the default main class and we want to run a different application via **docker exec** command

```
./gradlew clean bootRun -PmainClass=com.foo.BarApplication --args='--server.port=2222'
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use `docker exec` for this.  This is a debugging-oriented command that you can use to launch secondary processes in an existing container; you shouldn't need it in ordinary use, and it is not the right tool to launch a server-type application like a Spring application.

Instead, you'd generally `docker run` an second container.  You can have multiple containers launched from the same image, and you can specify an alternate command when you launch the container.

```sh
docker run -d --name second-container -p 2222:2222 \
  same/image:tag \
  ./gradlew clean bootRun -PmainClass=com.foo.BarApplication --args='--server.port=2222'
```

If you're using Docker Compose, you can similarly launch two services from the same image.  If it's something you're building locally, it's okay to specify `build: .` for both images; the second build will realize it's identical to the first one and complete very quickly.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  first:
    build: .
    ports: ['8000:8000']
  second:
    build: .
    ports: ['2222:2222']
    command: # I've chosen to split this out into a list to avoid quoting issues
      - ./gradlew
      - clean
      - bootRun
      - -PmainClass=com.foo.BarApplication
      - --args=--server.port=2222
```